# jQuery Mobile, DOM, and Event Unbindings

Tags: jquery, dom, mobile, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm currently working with jQuery mobile and have a quick question on how DOM in general works.  Currently, I bind events to elements on a page that was loaded via AJAX (page is inject into the DOM).

When a page transitions, according to the [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html), jQuery mobile removes the page from DOM.

Do I need to worry about unbinding jQuery events to elements that are no longer in DOM existence?  When I change a page via ajax, am I assured that the GC will clean up my bindings?

**TLDR**: When elements that were binded with jQuery [ `$(...).on("click" ...);` ] are removed from the DOM, do we have to worry about unbinding the events?  Or does javascript automagically know to remove those events?

Answer (score 2):

When you change pages, the browser will clean up everything from the previous page - you don't have to worry about that.

In jQuery, if you use jQuery's `.remove()` method to take something out of the DOM, then jQuery will clean up for you.  If you don't use `.remove()` and remove the DOM element manually, then it's possible that some jQuery state will not get cleaned up properly (like `.data()` info for example).